# How to get utf8 characters to show in a laravel project

Tags: php, html, laravel, web, utf-8

I'm currently building a website for a Polish company and having some trouble with the special signs showing up as a square with demo in it: img ->

"Weird demo replacement"
[image]

The text shown there comes from an API which does return the right characters. Because when I just var_dump the data I get the right characters.
img ->

"Var dump"
[image]

I simply loop over the variable and print out the title in the view like this:

```html
@foreach ($courses as $course)
  <div class="courses__course">
    <div class="courses__tag">NEW</div>
      <h1 class="text--dark">{{ $course->title }}</h1>
```

My page starts of with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
```

And I've already tried replacing the meta charset with

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Which still causes the same problem.

This problem seems to be present on all browsers on both my pc and mobile. (tested chrome, firefox & edge)

The laravel setup is as basic as it gets, literally just ran the installer and added some html, scss and a controller.

Comment: Maybe the font used doesn't support special characters. Which font do you use ?

Comment: Have you checked the generated markup? Does it contain the proper char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your font(Galano Grotesque DEMO Bold?) doesn't have the **ò** character.

Comment: God I'm an idiot for not thinking of that, thank you! (its Campton btw)